# What's the differences between imageview property and - (void)setImage:forState: in UIButton?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uibutton, imageview

I just tried to set a new image (UIImage object) for my UIButton using `myBtn.imageview.image =  newimg;` then I found it didn't work.

After that I get the correct solution that using `setImage:forState:` , the documentation about UIButton says "imageView is the button’s image view. (read-only)"

How should I get it? What's the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says(`"imageView is the button’s image view. (read-only)"`), it is a read only property and you cant just change the `imageView`. You have to use the recommended method `setImage:forState:`. Basically `UIButton` might be having a different implementation than what you are expecting and `myBtn.imageview.image` may not actually set the desired image to the button. `setImage:forState:` might be having an implementation which could be completely different from just setting `myBtn.imageview.image = newimg;`. By directly setting like in your question, you might get some unexpected results since the actual implementation is not executed.